# MySQL regex escape $

Tags: mysql, regex, escaping, wildcard

I have written an analysis on logfiles from a Microsoft IIS Server.
The complete log is pushed to a mysql datbase. The fields of my table are exact the same as in the log.

```
CREATE TABLE `iis_logging` (
    `ID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `DATE_TIME` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `LOG_DATE` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `LOG_TIME` TIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `S_SITENAME` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `S_COMPUTERNAME` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `S_IP` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `CS_METHOD` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `CS_URI_STEM` TEXT NULL,
    `CS_URI_QUERY` TEXT NULL,
    `S_PORT` INT(11) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `CS_USERNAME` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `C_IP` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `CS_VERSION` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `CS_USER_AGENT` TEXT NULL,
    `CS_COOKIE` TEXT NULL,
    `CS_REFERER` TEXT NULL,
    `CS_HOST` TEXT NULL,
    `SC_STATUS` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `SC_SUBSTATUS` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `SC_WIN32_STATUS` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `SC_BYTES` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `CS_BYTES` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `TIME_TAKEN` INT(11) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    INDEX `date_key` (`LOG_DATE`),
    INDEX `DATE_URL` (`LOG_DATE`, `CS_URI_STEM`(30)),
    INDEX `URL` (`CS_URI_STEM`(100))
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=82749372
;
```

Now I have written a query to get only some parts of this log:

```
select concat(LOG_DATE,' ', LOG_TIME) as VISIT_TS, CS_METHOD, CS_URI_STEM, CS_URI_QUERY, CS_REFERER, CS_USERNAME
from iis_logging 
where CS_USERNAME NOT REGEXP '-' and CS_USERNAME NOT REGEXP '_' 
order by LOG_DATE DESC , LOG_TIME DESC, CS_USERNAME DESC
limit 500
```

Inside the where clause I would like to filter the usernames to get rid of technical users. This query works quite well.
But some technical users re still inside my result. Their usernames end with a $.

Example:

> 0#.w|domain\technical1971$

How can I write a REGEX to get rid of them?
I would like to filter on the existing $, becaue I don't want to filter on fixed names.

I already tried: (not working)

```
and CS_USERNAME NOT REGEXP '[.dollar-sign.]'
```

and

```
and CS_USERNAME NOT REGEXP '\$'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just using the `LIKE` operator:

```
WHERE CS_USERNAME NOT LIKE '%$'
```

If you wanted to use `REGEXP`, then you would need to escape the `$` with *two* backslashes:

```
WHERE CS_USERNAME NOT REGEXP '\\$$'
```

This would match a literal dollar sign at the end of the string.  From the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html):

> To use a literal instance of a special character in a regular expression, precede it by two backslash () characters. The MySQL parser interprets one of the backslashes, and the regular expression library interprets the other.

Comment: sometimes it is so easy, used the like operator. thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
where CS_USERNAME NOT REGEXP '-' and CS_USERNAME NOT REGEXP '_'
```

-->

```
WHERE cs_username REGEXP '[^-_$]'
```

But that assumes that the `$` might occur anywhere in the name.  For only at the end:

```
WHERE cs_username NOT REGEXP '[-_]|[$]$'
```

Notes:

- `-` must be first in a character class, else it indicates a range.
- `[$]` is an alternative to escaping `$` -- by making a character class.
- By putting everything in a single `REGEXP`, there is a slight improvement over using `AND` or `OR`.

  order by LOG_DATE DESC , LOG_TIME DESC, CS_USERNAME DESC

needs

```
INDEX(log_date, log_time, cs_username)
```